# Control background audio volume

Tags: android, ios, cordova, audio, cordova-plugins

We're developing a Cordova app with audio narration and directions, but when our app audio plays any other audio the device is playing gets paused.

We'd like users to be able to listen to music etc from other apps when using our app.

**Is there a way of preventing the background audio being paused and instead reducing the volume of background audio from Cordova?**

I've had a look around for Cordova plugins but can't see anything relevant.  NB. We're developing an app for use on Android and iPhone.

Thanks, Tom

Comment: UPDATE: From some digging we've found a couple of things, but both aren't quite right for what we need:

**Only works with iOS:**
https://github.com/davidfig/cordova-allow-background-audio

**Only works with Angular js framework** (we're not using this for our app)
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio

Really feels like there should be a solution!  I'm sure there must be other Cordova apps that have some audio but want people to be able to listen to music whilst they use

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using xamarin? I rewrote my Cordova app to use xamarin and haven't looked back.
Good luck